# Set background color to match default mesh color

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I try to render animation which contains a plane with moving mesh objects on top of it. Currently, the camera can see the background which results in color difference between the plane and the background.
How can I make the background color to match the plane default color?
How can I do that using script?

Comment: Do you want the plane to disappear entirely? (Just don't render it).. or something else? Could you illustrate?

Comment: No this is not what I meant at all. I want the background color to match to planes defalut color (kind of a gray color)